# Gunicorn import error: url_for not found in flask, but native flask run works fine

Tags: python, heroku, flask, gunicorn

I can run my flask app fine using flask's built-in web server command run(), but I'm receiving the following Import error while trying to run my app using gunicorn.  I use the command gunicorn project.app:app from the mainfolder.

The error being thrown off from views.py is:

```
from app import db, url_for ImportError: cannot import name url_for
```

My app is organized as follows:

```
mainfolder/
    Procfile
    bin
    project/
        app.py
        _config.py
        views.py
        run.py
```

**run.py**

```
from views import app
import os
port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('_config.py')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'], report_errors=False)

from views import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

**_config.py**

```
import os
#All the app's keys
```

**Procfile**

```
#this works fine
web: python project/run.py

#this doesn't work
web: gunicorn project.app:app
```

python project/app.py runs the app fine so why does gunicorn project.app:app throw off a module ImportError?

Comment: Why are you importing url_for from app? url_for comes from flask

Comment: url_for is being imported from views.py.  I'll edit the original to reflect that.

Comment: Have you tried importing url_for from flask - `from flask import url_for` also, you need to import it before your app is instantiated (the top of the file).

Comment: Ah, I'm importing url_for from flask in views.py.  Should it be imported in app.py as well?

Comment: Okay, good. Finally - the import for url_for in `app.py` needs to come before your `app = Flask(__name__)`... Gunicorn doesn't use the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block.

Comment: Great - thank you Patrick - made some progress as the ImportError is gone, but worker times out with
[2015-08-23 14:13:35 +0800] [2507] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2507
[2015-08-23 14:14:07 +0800] [2504] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:2507)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87677/discussion-between-sal-and-patrick-allen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import for url_for needs to come before `app = Flask(__name__)`

Your app is working on flask's server because url_for is imported prior to the

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

statement. Gunicorn is getting the application before you have imported url_for.